# Writing code in a line without starting new line

Tags: latex

When I write code in platex using `{lstlisting}`

```
\begin{lstlisting}
if True:
   print("latex")
\end{lstlisting}
```

However how can I put the code in the sentence??

like the ` in stackoverflow.

I want to show like below

"Please look at this code `print("latex")` ,this code is nice"

Comment: there is an inline listings macro. Can you make a compilable [mre]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `\lstinline` macro:

```
\documentclass{jarticle}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}


test \lstinline|code| test

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Also, the core macro `verb`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Text text text \verb|code \ @ } code| text text.

\end{document}
```

Not only braces and vertical bars `|` can delimit the content or argument here (see the comments below) but any other character, as long as it is the same before and after and not part of the the inline code. For example `\verb!code \ @ } code!` will work just as well.

As you can see, special characters need no escape within `verb`.

Comment: `\verb` is a core macro, you don't need the `verbatim` package for it

Comment: Instead of the vertical bars, curly parenthesis are also possible or just about any other character as long as it is the same before and after and not part of the the inline code

Comment: For example `\verb!code \ @ } code!` will work just as well as `|`

Comment: Thank you @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz for clarifying this particular fact!!