# Insert inline code block in Latex document

Tags: latex

Hi I am trying to add an inline code block in a Latex document. I know how to add a separate code block using lstlisting but i want to instead add an inline code block. I am attaching the screenshot of output that i am expecting .

[image]

As you can see in the same line a code block is added which contains the expression `print(g)`. I want something like that. So that it should be customizable, that is., the background color of the box, width and height of the box, border width etc .Also the text of the code inside that inline code block should be customizable as well .Is there a way to achieve this in Latex?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286094/insert-code-keywords-inline

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing code in a line without starting new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66105087/writing-code-in-a-line-without-starting-new-line)

Answer (score 23):

A very simple way may be:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

The command \verb|print(g)| prints something.

\end{document}
```

And you can take some more sophisticated style from [this TeX SE thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/357227/49683).

Do not forget that, as in the page linked above, [`listings`](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) package itself also allow to style inline code.